# Why is something looking for VsixUtil.exe here?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I have a solution that's a VS extension, that compiles to a VSIX. I deleted my packages folder, built the solution, and I get an error...
`The specified task executable location "D:\git\QueryFirst\packages\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.15.0.26201\tools\VSSDK\bin\VsixUtil.exe" is invalid.`

The folder exists, but sure enough VsixUtil.exe is not in it. I installed VsixUtil with nuget, but it doesn't go to that location. Why is my solution looking for VsixUtil in that location. Can I point it somewhere else? Or install it there?

I'm on VS 2017 Enterprise.

Comment: They do manage to break nuget packages, agilely, try an older version.  Note that the package version numbers appear to match the VS2017 update numbers so using one that roughly matches yours might be wise.  Help > About shows the number.

Comment: I don't understand at all. What needs to match? The version of VsixUtil against the version of VS ?

Comment: The nuget package makes big changes to the way your project gets built.  Unraveling it is going to take you a while, there are rather a lot of paths, .targets, .dll and .exe files involved.  It is supposed to "just work" but that is an ideal that is not always achieved in VS2017.  The older the version of the package, the less likely that it still has undiagnosed bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VsixUtil.exe utility should not be downloaded/installed separately. The NuGet package that you have used to download is not "official" from Microsoft or VisualStudioExtensibility.

Apparently there is a version mismatch in your project between two VSSDKs:

- the project is using a recent Microsoft.VsSDK.targets file that uses the VsixUtil task:

> ```
>   <UsingTask TaskName="VsixUtil" AssemblyFile="$(VsSDKAssemblyFile)" />
> ```

- but it is going to the folder of an old VSSDK (Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.15.0.26201) that doesn't have the VsixUtil.exe file required for that task.

Upgrade your Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools NuGet package of your project to use the latest versions 15.8.x ( 15.8.3252 or 15.8.3247) that do include VsixUtil.exe in the folder tools\vssdk\bin.

Comment: Worked. I needed to manually delete the reference to the old version of the build tools in the csproj, but that fixed it.